# Question about the Picard's Theorem applying on $y'=y^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

According to the Picard's Theorem:

If $f(x,y)$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ are continuous on a closed rectangle $R$ with sides parallel to the axes and if $(x_0,y_o)$ is any interior point in $R$, then there exists a number $h>0$ s.t. the initial value problem:
$$y'=f(x,y), \qquad y(x_0) = y_0 $$
has unique solution $y = y(x)$ on the interval $|x-x_0|\leq h$.

However, consider the following IVP:
$$ y'= y^2, \qquad y(x_0) = y_0$$
Since $f(x,y) = y^2$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 2y$ are continuous on the entire plane, it is seems that the solution is valid for all $x$ and $y$. However since the differential equation is separable we can solve it directly and yield:$$-\frac{1}{ y} = x+C$$ where y is obvious not $0$. How should we explain this contradiction?

Comment: I don't  see your contradiction.

Comment: Picard's Theorem promises you a unique solution to the intial value problem in some interval $\;[x_0-\epsilon,\,x_0+\epsilon]\;$ ...what has $\;y=0\;$ to do here?

Comment: The other solution can be written $y(x) = \frac{y_0}{1 - y_0(x-x_0)}$. If you impose $y(x_0) = 0$ then $y_0 = 0$ so this other solution is identical to the $y\equiv 0$ solution.

Comment: thank you very much，i noticed my mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you solve this equation by separating the variables, you are dividing by $y^2$ and hence your solution is only valid for $y \ne 0$.  According to the theorem, given any $x_0$, there *is* a solution with $y(x_0)=0$. But separation of variables is not a valid method to find it.